# MYSQL altering table field type

Tags: mysql

I want to change my SQL table field type to FULLTEXT. Because MATCH function not working. Is there any possibilities of data loss to altering the table field??

Comment: **1.** add new temp fulltext column
**2.** update new_temp_col = original_column
**3.** select count(*) where original_column != new_temp_col
**4.** drop old column, rename new column to old column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is always risk of data loss. So before you update the table type, make a backup. So whatever happens, you are safe (at least more safer than losing data).

Answer (score 0):

Make a dump of the table data only. Then change the field type, in case of data lose you can restore easily.

```
mysqldump --no-create-info --complete-insert <db> <table>
```